# Motion tracking rotation too small

Tags: tracking

After solving my video I see that the rotations are too small (I rotate panoramic in 180 degrees, and then back halfway again, but camera only rotates 90 degrees). Any tips on what can cause this? The overall rotation looks right but should be twice as big.

There are variations in both altitude and depth in the video, the sidewalk on the other side of the river is maybe 3 meters higher (filmed here (59.8588332, 17.6356057)). The water level was low so rocks were easy to track. Also houses and the brick wall.

I did not use a tripod just handheld cellphone, but I did not move it much.

I want to be able to put models in the water.

Comment: Did you set the reference scale? Related: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42329/31447)

Comment: I did... But maybe I should use different reference points and tweak scale until it looks good, if that can affect the rotation.

Comment: I joined tracks from when I rotated back, and got some improvements on the rotation.